# laravel 5.6 keep array custom key in resource response

Tags: php, laravel, api

from laravel documentation:
The withoutWrapping method only affects the outer-most response and will not remove data keys that you manually add to your own resource collections.

i use Resource::withoutWrapping();

```
`"status": "success"
    "entry": {
        "access_control": [
            1 => {
                "allowed": [
                    0 => "015"
                    1 => "002"
                    2 => "011"
                 ]
}`
```

in laravel 5.6 i can't define custom array key, key under `access_control` key become 0.'

How to make api resource support custom key?

Answer (score 2):

Array key are removed when the [JsonResource](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Http/Resources/Json/JsonResource.php#L88) applies it's [filter](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Http/Resources/ConditionallyLoadsAttributes.php#L15) method. There does not seem a way to retain those keys.

For my particular use case, I was able to refactor the array value to include it's "id" - in your case:

```
"access_control": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "allowed": [
            "015"
            "002"
            "011"
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way around this would be to use stdClass();

```
$array = new \stdClass();
$array->access_control = ['somedata'];
```

Then it should pass it as an object.